# Responsive image parent width not resizing

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a row of responsive images set to 100% height and auto width wrapped in divs with a flexible height. The problem is the width of the parent divs is not changing reliably on browser resize, leaving gaps or overlaps in chrome and ie.

```
<div><img></div>
<div><img></div>

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #f3f;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kyucun6b/1/

This is for my portfolio so people will definitely be resizing the browser, otherwise I probably wouldn't worry about it. Thanks.

Comment: how is it supposed to work? mb `width: 30vh` for `div`

Comment: Hi Andrey, did you notice the issue I'm talking about when you resize the browser? Happens most times in chrome, always in ie, where the parent doesn't resize to the child width. If all works well, you should never see any purple bg. The images will be variable in width in the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the end was so simple I can't believe it took so long to discover. If you move the height to the images and give them a display: block it works as desired and the parent div resizes perfectly.

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f3f;
}
img {
  height: 30vh;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kyucun6b/5/